# PowerShell, Output from creating a directory

Tags: powershell, mkdir

When I create a directory with PowerShell on the console, using `New-Item C:\Temp -Item-Type Directory` or the `mkdir` function, `mkdir C:\Temp`, I get short/concise feedback

```
    Directory: C:\

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        19/12/2022     21:31                Temp
```

However, if I run these from a script, I get hugely verbose output for some reason!

```
PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Temp
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\
PSChildName       : Folder View Defaults
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : True
Name              : Temp
FullName          : C:\Temp
Parent            : Temp
Exists            : True
Root              : C:\
Extension         :
CreationTime      : 12/19/2022 8:52:30 PM
CreationTimeUtc   : 12/19/2022 8:52:30 PM
LastAccessTime    : 12/19/2022 8:52:30 PM
LastAccessTimeUtc : 12/19/2022 8:52:30 PM
LastWriteTime     : 12/19/2022 8:52:30 PM
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 12/19/2022 8:52:30 PM
Attributes        : Directory
Mode              : d-----
BaseName          : Temp
Target            : {}
LinkType          :
```

Why does it output all of this information (from a script), and how can I tame the output of this from a script so that it just shows a simple confirmation that the folder was created?

I am doing everything in PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10, and just running a normal `.ps1` script, an example of lines that behave like the above:

```
$backup = "$env:TEMP\Folder View Defaults"
mkdir $backup -Force
```

Comment: Do you have PowerShell (Core) 7.3.1 (or earlier) installed? Are you running pwsh.exe or a different executable?

Comment: You need to give us some of the script code to decipher

Comment: I'm doing everything on PS 5.1 for compatibility, and the particular script is about 10,000 lines long. Various lines cause the above, for example, the first one I found that outputs verbose as above: `$backup = "$env:TEMP\Folder View Defaults"; mkdir $backup -Force`.

Answer (score 0):

*how can I tame the output*

You can always pipe to `Select-Object` to only returm the info you want like

```
New-Item -Path "$env:TEMP\Folder View Defaults" -ItemType Directory -Force | Select-Object Mode,LastWriteTime,Name
```

or if you just want confirmation ($true or $false) do

```
[bool](New-Item -Path "$env:TEMP\Folder View Defaults" -ItemType Directory -Force)
```